# On Oracle Fusion AR - where is the accounting date for Receipt is located (Database level)?

Tags: oracle-fusion-apps

I am unable to locate the accounting date for Receipts on Oracle tables for Receivables. I have examined the following tables:
ar_cash_receipts_all,
ar_cash_receipt_history_all,
ar_receivable_applications_all,
ar_payment_schedules_all

Anyone has a query that can get this for Receipts, that will be a huge help.
Thanks